# auto load components from folder

Tags: javascript

How can I **auto** import **all** components within a folder?

If for example I have a folder `MyFolder` and within it I have bunch of `ComponentOne`, `ComponentTwo`(component's name may vary), so instead of explicitly write a name of each and every component I want to import, I want to use it somehow like this: `import bunchOfComponents from "./MyFolder"`, so I could iterate over it after and decide what to do with it.

Comment: Can you specify what framework you're using (if any?) -- for example, if you're using Vite or Nuxt or just plain Node.JS -- regardless, [this post may answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984955/how-to-import-all-components-in-react)

Comment: don't know which framework you are using but you can use this technique in most frameworks `import * as bunchOfComp from './MyFolder'` and you can use it as `bunchOfComp.ComponentOne`. since, i don't know which framework you are using, can't exactly tell how to use these imported components

Comment: @LeoDog896 I use React, but want to use this in plain javascript as well.

Comment: @MohammadDanish It's not possible, it doesn't load this way. I need to create something in-between so this method will apply. So to say import and export in index.js of the MyFolder, but I don't want to do that, that's the whole point of this question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck